# Bind_param with value 0

Tags: php, mysqli, bindparam

When I execute:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE ColumnName = ?');
$tmp = 0;
$stmt->bind_param('i', $tmp);
```

I receive the error:

> No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement

I have to do the following to make it work.

```
$tmp = "0";
$stmt->bind_param('i', $tmp);
```

Is it normal?
This problem happens only when I insert `0`. Any other integer work.

Comment: neither would work because bind_param won't accept a constant value but a variable only.

Comment: i edited the answer

Comment: can you add the query you want to execute?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE ColumnName = ?` where ? i bind 0 (see above)

Comment: This post lacks a minimal, complete, and verifiable example.

Comment: No, this is not normal. Please supply your php and db version; on php 5.6 (mysql 5.5.49) it seems to work with $tmp's value 0, null, false and even when it's undeclared.

Comment: Yay for typos, parameter missing leading `:`.

Answer (score -1):

## Incorrectly labeled params

Make sure that all of your parameters are prefixed with `:`, both in the statement definition, and in `bind_param()`.

```
$PHPPDO->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE status =:i');

$tmp = 0;
$stmt->bind_param(':i', $tmp);
```

#### Unlikely, but could be a data-type-juggling issue with whatever version of PHP/PHPPDO you're using.

Try using `intval()`, and/or explicitly declaring the datatype (depending on php version).

```
$tmp = (int) 0;  // php < 5.1
$tmp = intval(0); // php 5.2+ (though on these versions, it probably isn't the datatype.
```

#### Older versions of PHPPDO(and PHP) re: MySql vs MS SQL.

MySql has some built-in type juggling, such that with a `NULL` parameter sent to `UPDATE` or `INSERT` to an `INT` column, will be converted to `0`. However, older versions of MS SQL do not do this type-juggling for you.